# porque me sale que el map esta undefined

Tags: reactjs

Estoy utilizando react js y nose porque el map de "productos.map" salta error. Me dice que es undefined y no se porque. Esta todo bien linkeado  y bien estructurado. Nose si alguno me podria dar una mano. Adjunto imagenes

```
const ItemList = ({productos}) => {
return (
<div className="contenedorProductos">
    {
    productos.map(prod  => {
        return <Item key={prod.id}  {...prod} />
    })
    }


</div>

)
```

}

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: a nivel sintaxis entiendo que el codigo que indicaste esta correcto. El error por lo que se puede ser por estas dos cosas, que el valor pasado por prop no sea un arreglo o que sea 'undefined'. Esto es lo unico que se me viene a la cabeza con la info que brindas. Ojala te sirva, Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Sugiero revisar desde el componente padre si se esta pasando el array `productos`, ya que el error dice que no esta definido. Sin embargo se puede implementar lo siguiente.

#### Manejo de Optional Props

Se puede usar *optional chaining operator* `?` para verificar que el array `productos` existe antes de llamar al metodo `map`, si el array es `undefined` o `null` map no se llamará y no habrá nada que renderizar, ni tampoco se disparan errores:

```
const ItemList = ({productos}) => {
    return (
        <div className="contenedorProductos">
         {
          productos?.map(prod  => {
             return <Item key={prod.id}  {...prod} />
          })
         }
        </div>
)}
```